# Android Developer Tools (ADT) not visible from console

Tags: android, eclipse, windows, adt

I've installed ADT via marketplace in STS, Android SDK is installed, but I can't run 'adt' from cmd, I get message that says its not recognized as command. What am I doing wrong? My PATH variable is:

> Path=C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AMDAPP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\ATI
>   Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows
>   Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe
>   AIR;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;
>
> ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\sdk
>
> Android SDK location in STS is C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\sdk

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed in C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\sdks sdk in versions 4.6 and 4.12.1. Default for my STS is 4.12.1 but adt was installed in 4.6 only. I copied adt files to 4.12.1 and everything is working fine.